# cannot set date input value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still not that experienced with HTML and JavaScript but I have been stumbled on this one and have no clue why does it not work.

I have the following code

```js
function DateConverter(date) {
  let dateArray = date.split(".");
  let dateFormatted = dateArray[1] + "-" + dateArray[0] + "-" + dateArray[2];
  return dateFormatted;
}

//ajax for LoadingDataInDetais
$("#taskList").change(function(event) {
  let a = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Taskview?handler=GrabTask&taskId=" + $(this).val(),
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      var task = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#task_City').val(task["name"]);
      $('#task_Location').val(task["loc"]);
      $('#task_Client').val(task["client"]);
      $('#task_Number').val(task["taskNo"]);
      $('#task_Date').val(DateConverter(task["date"]));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!--Other fields above-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-8 date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <label class="control-label">Date</label>
  <input id="task_Date" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" />
</div>
```

All other fields have their values set correctly but the 'date' one does not and I have no clue why. I even tried with plain java script but it just doesn't work. The console doesn't say anything.

The date from the ajax comes in the format "dd.MM.yyyy" and I tried converting it to some other format but all to no avail

Can someone shed some light into the problem;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7LXPq/93/ this may help

Comment: @Developer so the problem is in the format as it should be yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: @Developer it helper. Post it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the wrong values in your formatter:

```
function DateConverter(date) {
    return date.split('.').reverse().join('-');
}
```

Comment: Oneliner feels more expressive: `return date.split('.').reverse().join('-');`